# Find limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} n \left(n^2\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right) + n \log\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) $

Tags: limits

Define $a_n$ as:

$$
a_n = \left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^n
$$

Now I want to calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$. So, real question is about other limit.

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^2} \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)^n
$$

As $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^2} \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = 1$, we cannot conclude limit in easy way. ($1^{\infty}$ case.) I don't know, what I should do now.

I tried:

$$
\ln \left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^2} \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right) =
n \left(n^2\ln(1+\frac{1}{n^2}) + n \ln(1-\frac{1}{n})\right)
$$

So, now problematic is limit:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} n \left(n^2\ln(1+\frac{1}{n^2}) + n \ln(1-\frac{1}{n})\right)
$$

It's not better. How should I calculate this limit?

Comment: Hint: $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n^2})^{n^2}=e$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n}= \frac 1e$

Comment: True, but I don't see, how it should help.

Comment: Write as $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {\ln{((1+ \frac 1{n^2})^{n^2}(1- \frac 1n)^n)}}{n^{-1}}$ then you have a "$\frac 00$" case, apply l'hopitals rule

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure if it can work. It's very unpleasant derivative. If you see a way to calculate it by hand that way. Please, submit your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_n$ be the sequence given by $f_n=n \left(n^2\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right) + n \log\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$.  We can evaluate the limit of $f_n$ by expanding the logarithm functions embedded in the limit of interest as

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n&=\lim_{n \to \infty} n \left(n^2\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right) + n \log\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} n\left(n^2\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)+n\left(-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)\right)\\\\
&=-\frac12
\end{align}$$

Comment: I just saw it. However, thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're quite welcome.  My pleasure!